# Android Send sms with link and open application

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Problem: I can send links through sms using my application.
         How do i make my application start when user clicks on the link. if my application is not installed, i want the user to be re directed to `google play`.

I  send  sms as

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.application", smsSent, smsDelivered);
```

The message with the link is being delivered.

my android manifest file is

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.my.app.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <data
                android:host="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.app"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When the user clicks on the link the option of browser and google play is coming up even when my application is installed in that phone.The application is already there in app store

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the market URI scheme.

You are using `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.application` , but you have to use `market://details?id=com.my.application`

`market://` is correct

`https://play.....` is wrong